# How to play a simple .wav type sound in C# Windows Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, audio

I was making a simple Pong game and wanted to play a sound when the ball hits walls. Code is ready even the place is ready where i must place sound.play function. I tried doing it but when ball hits the wall Form Application just freezes and i have to force close visual studio. Any suggestion why this happens?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Media;

namespace P3_7_26_2016_Pong
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public int speed_left = 4;
        public int speed_top = 4;
        public int points = 0;
        /* PLAYER INITIALIZED HERE */
        private SoundPlayer Player = new SoundPlayer();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            Cursor.Hide();
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.TopMost = true;
            this.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;

            pong.Top = playground.Bottom - (playground.Bottom / 10);

            gameoverLabel.Left = (playground.Width / 2) - (gameoverLabel.Width / 2);
            gameoverLabel.Top = (playground.Height / 2) - (gameoverLabel.Height / 2);
            gameoverLabel.Visible = false;

            //SOUND SET HERE
            Player.SoundLocation = @"C:\Users\bacon\Desktop\click.wav";
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pong.Left = Cursor.Position.X - (pong.Width / 2);
            ball.Left += speed_left;
            ball.Top += speed_top;
            if(ball.Bottom >= pong.Top && ball.Bottom <= pong.Bottom && ball.Left >= pong.Left && ball.Right <= pong.Right)
            {
                speed_left += 2;
                speed_top += 2;
                //speed_left = -speed_left;
                speed_top = -speed_top;
                points += 1;
                pointsLabel.Text = points.ToString();

                Random r = new Random();
                playground.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(r.Next(150, 255), r.Next(150, 255), r.Next(150, 255));

                /* SOUND PLAYED HERE */
                Player.Play();
            }
            if(ball.Left <= playground.Left)
            {
                speed_left = -speed_left;
            }
            if(ball.Right >= playground.Right)
            {
                speed_left = -speed_left;
            }
            if(ball.Top <= playground.Top)
            {
                speed_top = -speed_top;
            }
            if(ball.Bottom >= playground.Bottom)
            {
                timer1.Enabled = false;
                gameoverLabel.Visible = true;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape) { this.Close(); }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)
            {
                ball.Top = 50;
                ball.Left = 50;
                speed_left = 4;
                speed_top = 4;
                points = 0;
                pointsLabel.Text = "";
                timer1.Enabled = true;
                gameoverLabel.Visible = false;
                playground.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **i bolded sound play codes**

Comment: Bolding does not work in code snippets

Comment: well its still highlights Code fragments

Comment: Put `Player.Play()` within a try/catch block, and output the exception somewhere. (Post it here if you still need help). Also: You should be able to add a breakpoint right before and catch the exception as it happens.

Comment: but why use try catch, its if statement . if statements is true it should play sound